# text processing ignore 2nd occurence of underscore

Tags: unix, awk, text-processing

data shld be ignored from 2nd occurence of underscore, this should be sorted and duplicated need to be eliminated.

```
awk -F_ '{print $2}' file1 >> file 2; sort file1 | uniq ; i tried
```

******FROM********

```
GGGGGGG             DDDDD   --> header
XYSER_YURTZ     SUMOT_2_058A     
XYSER_YURTZ     SUMOT_2_058B    
XYSER_YURTZ     HJRIT_6_51A     
XYSER_YURTZ     HJRIT_6_51B     
XYSER_YURTZ     HJRIT_6_51C    
XYSER_YURTZ     HJRIT_6_51D    
XYSER_YURTZ     HJRIT_6_51E    
XYSER_YURTZ     HJRIT_6_51F    
XYSER_YURTZ     HJRIT_6_520    
XYSER_YURTZ     HJRIT_6_521    
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16C3    
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16C4    
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16C5    
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16C6  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16C7  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16C8  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16C9  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16CA  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16CB  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16CC   
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16CD  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16CE   
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16CF  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16D0  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16D1  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16D2  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16D3  
XYSER_GFRE      SUMOT_2_16D4  
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E1    
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E2    
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E3    
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E4    
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E5   
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E6   
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E7   
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E8   
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12E9   
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12EA   
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12EB   
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12EC   
XYSER_GFRE      HJRIT_6_12ED   
XYSER_ALY1      XYSER_ALY1_0000   
XYSER_ALY       SUMOT_2_0497   
XYSER_ALY       SUMOT_2_0498   
XYSER_BAP01     SUMOT_2_020E
```

TO

**************OUTPUT1**************

```
GGGGGGG DDDDD   
XYSER_YURTZ SUMOT_2   
XYSER_YURTZ HJRIT_6   
XYSER_GFRE SUMOT_2   
XYSER_GFRE HJRIT_6   
XYSER_ALY1 XYSER_ALY1   
XYSER_ALY SUMOT_2       
XYSER_BAP01 SUMOT_2   
XYSER_BAP02 SUMOT_2
```

**************OUTPUT2**************

```
DDDDD GGGGGGG   
SUMOT_2 XYSER_YURTZ  
SUMOT_2 XYSER_GFRE  
SUMOT_2 XYSER_ALY  
SUMOT_2 XYSER_BAP01  
SUMOT_2 XYSER_BAP02  
HJRIT_6 XYSER_YURTZ  
HJRIT_6 XYSER_GFRE  
XYSER_ALY1 XYSER_ALY1
```

Comment: Good for showing sample data, outputs AND code! Can you possible reduce the amount of input to about 10 lines AND you need to show us a sample of required output based on the input. Please label int `required output` (right?). Show your current output as  well and describe the problem (I think you have done that). Good luck.

Comment: With your example input you can use `sed 's/_[^_]*$//' inputfile|sort|uniq`. This will remove the last underscore and all following characters.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your example input you can use

```
sed 's/_[^_]*$//' inputfile|sort|uniq
```

This will remove the last underscore and all following characters.

Note: The `sort` command may put the header between the other rows because it will sort the whole data alphanumerically. In your example this is not a problem because the header line `GGGGGGG...` will be sorted before `XYSER_...`.

If you know that the similar lines are already grouped in your input file you can omit the sorting and use

```
sed 's/_[^_]*$//' inputfile|uniq
```